# how to hide widgets with checkbox in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

value = 0

def add_one():
    global value
    value += 1
    label2.config(text=value)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x115")

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='   ')
label1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(root, text=0)
label2.pack()

label3 = tk.Label(root, text='   ')
label3.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=add_one)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

how do i add a checkbox that checking shows a hidden button(s) that gives you like a 1000 clicks when clicked

like a show cheats checkbox

Comment: *gives you like a 1000 clicks when clicked* Can you explain this

Comment: If you want to hide a widget, use: `widget.pack_forget()` if you used `widget.pack()` to put the widget on he screen.

Comment: seems like you are asking two questions (not ideal for SO), first on how to show/hide a widget and second on how to perform 1000 clicks (also you haven't specified if they have to be global or only bound to tkinter window (tho bound to window are prob slightly harder))

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
import tkinter as tk

value = 0

def add_one():
    global value
    value += 1
    label2.config(text=value)

def add_thousand():
    global value
    value += 1000
    label2.config(text=value)

def nayta_tuhatnappi():
    button_piilossa.pack(pady=10)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x215")

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='   ')
label1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(root, text=0)
label2.pack()

label3 = tk.Label(root, text='   ')
label3.pack()

#Luodaan valintalaatikko, ja yhdistetään siihen komento...
valintalaatikko=tk.Checkbutton(root,text='Olen ymmärtänyt kaiken',command=nayta_tuhatnappi)
valintalaatikko.pack(pady=10)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=add_one)
button.pack()

#luodaan painike mutta ei vielä näytetä sitä...
button_piilossa=tk.Button(root,text="Boost",command=add_thousand)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ...using .pack_forget() ... shown in Answer II

Answer (score 0):

Answer II (with hiding feature):

```
import tkinter as tk

value = 0

def add_one():
    global value
    value += 1
    label2.config(text=value)

def add_thousand():
    global value
    value += 1000
    label2.config(text=value)
    #Käytön jälkeen piilotetaan buttoni
    button_piilossa.pack_forget()

def nayta_tuhatnappi():
    button_piilossa.pack(pady=10)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x215")

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='   ')
label1.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(root, text=0)
label2.pack()

label3 = tk.Label(root, text='   ')
label3.pack()

#Luodaan valintalaatikko, ja yhdistetään siihen komento...
valintalaatikko=tk.Checkbutton(root,text='Olen ymmärtänyt kaiken',command=nayta_tuhatnappi)
valintalaatikko.pack(pady=10)

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=add_one)
button.pack()

#luodaan painike mutta ei vielä näytetä sitä...
button_piilossa=tk.Button(root,text="Boost",command=add_thousand)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: yeah i meant like getting sthe state of the checkbox and if it's checked show the boost button and if not hide it not like hiding when the button is clicked